# Как перенести большую базу MySQL?

Tags: база-данных, php, mysql

Нужно перенести базу большого размера, около 94 метров в .sql формате. Дело осложняет то, что старый хостинг работает на доисторической версии phpMyAdmin и не умеет правильно паковать все в архив. (скопировано в архиме 86к из 156к строчек)

На хостинге куда я ставлю базу, максимальный размер файла 64мб. Как мне дописать оставшиеся строки?

Comment: 94 метра - это совсем небольшая база, сорри за оффтоп

Answer (score 2):

Если база поддерживает подключение не с локального хоста, советую использовать `dbforge studio for mysql`. У меня тоже был головняк с базами на несколько ГБ, пришлось вот так делать.

Answer (score 2):

Если хостинг поддерживание подключения не с локально хоста, то можно стандартной консольной утилитой `mysqldump`:

```
mysqldump --host=blablabla.com --port=3306 --user=user --password=password --compress databasename > databasename.sql
```

Обращаешься к базе удаленно, а резервную копию получаешь сразу в `databasename.sql` на своем компьютере.

**UPD:** Для распаковки базы из резервной копии:

```
mysql --host=blablabla.com --port=3306 --user=user --password=password --compress databasename < databasename.sql
```

Опять же, дамп на твоем компьютере, а база разворачивается на хостинге.

Comment: Нет, базу я выгрузил, а полностью загрузить на новый хостинг не могу из за ограничения по весу.

Comment: У тебя есть ssh доступ к сайту на новом хостинге?
Если есть то загрузишь, если нет, то выложи этот файл куда нить на хостинг и попроси хостеров залить в нужную БД этот дамп они обязаны сделать это :)

Comment: Если есть доступ к ssh, то там проще можно `gzip` и `cat` использовать, На старом хостинге:

    mysqldump databasename | gzip -9 | split -b 64M - databasename.sql.gz.

На новом

    cat databasename.sql.gz.* | gzip -d | mysql databasename

Comment: @Happy_Cougar, можно руками разделить SQL-файл на блоки, и загружать его в базу блоками. По сути, резервная копия - это набор запросов типа `CREATE TABLE` и `INSERT INTO`.

Comment: @KiTE - не знаю, у меня большой дамп ни один текстовый редактор не проглатывал :)

Comment: Можно воспользоваться EmEditor-ом. Он умеет открывать большие файлы посегментно. Я ним 5Gb дамп правил. Правда, сохранялись изменения очень долго, ну это и понятно. И, если это существенно, EmEditor - платный.

Еще можно дамп делать не всей базы целиком, а пакетами по несколько таблиц:

    mysqldump --host=blablabla.com --port=3306 --user=user --password=password database table_1 table_2 table_n > file.sql

Comment: Я пакетми и делал, просто в вопросе речь о большой БД, посему решил что в данном конкретном случае это довольно таки важная "мелочь"

Про EmEditor - спс, посмотрю

Answer (score 2):

```
<?
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$fn = 'new.sql';
$DBHOST = 'localhost';
$DBUSER = 'root';
$DBPASS = 'pass';
$DBNAME = 'db';
mysql_connect($DBHOST, $DBUSER, $DBPASS) or die('#1');
mysql_select_db($DBNAME) or die('#2');
mysql_query('SET NAMES UTF8;') or die('#3');
if (!$f = fopen($fn, 'rb')) die('#4');
$q = $qp = '';
$qOk = false;
$n = 0;
while (!feof($f)) {
  $n++;
  $qp = trim(fgets($f));
  if ($qp{0}=='#') continue;
  $q .= $qp;
  if ($q{strlen($q)-1}==';') $qOk = true;
  if ($qOk) {
    echo '| ';
    @flush();
    if (!mysql_query($q)) die('#5<pre> Line '.$n.': '.htmlspecialchars($q)."\n\n".mysql_error().'</pre>');
    $q = '';
    $qOk = false;
    }
  }
fclose($f);
echo '<hr />ok';
?>
```

Моя наработка. Пригодилась) Учтите, что она пригодна только для заливки дампов `phpmyadmin` в `utf8` без какой-то обработки. Запускать аккуратно, один раз. Не обновлять страницу. В идеале после заливки удалить скрипт.

*ЗЫ* заливал 400-метровую БД, глюков не замечено.

Comment: Будут проблемы если:

1. `;` встретится в строке
2. в SQL-файле используется `DELIMITER`

Comment: 1 не будут, учтено

2 phpmyadmin такого не делает

Comment: 1. какой обход?) myadmin пишет любой текст в одну строку

    INSERT ... (
      "value;\n\t\123<br>", # это одна строка, несмотря на ; и \n
      ...
      ); # это конец обработки

2. вот честно, именно по работе в веб ни с чем из этого не столкнулся за 5 лет. Алсо, я не претендую на универсальность(хайлоад, веб-приложения и прочее), но утилитка подойдет для абсолютного большинства сайтов. Плюс человек, который с этим встречался, имхо, решил бы вопрос сам)

Comment: > Я правильно понимаю?

Нет о_О Зачем она там?

Comment: Формат SQL зависит от настроек экспорта. По умолчанию он такого типа:
    
    INSERT INTO tablename (f1, f2, ..., f3) VALUES
    (..., 'строка', ...),
    ...
    (...);

Проверено на версии 3.4.3.1.
Именно поэтому я и спросил, как Вы обрабатываете `;` внутри строковой константы...

Comment: По поводу 2 возможно Вы правы. Я не работаю со стандартными движками. И во всю использую программируемую логику БД. А движках, для унивесальности, эти вещи скорее всего не используются.

Comment: Строки я читаю из дампа, просто восстанавливаю запрос, а что там у него внутри, меня не особо волнует. "**;**" стоит последним символом строки только в конце запроса.

Comment: Теперь понял, спасибо :)

Answer (score 1):

Можно частями, группами таблиц.
Или хостера об этом попроси..

Answer (score 1):

Попробовать использовать `sypex dumper`.

Answer (score 1):

Бери sypex dumper, желательно профессиональную версию. Хотя для 94 мб и лайт подойдет. Просто проф. версия может загружать таблицы отдельно.